# Accessing Method in WebAPI via Put Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

My apologies if the question seems trivial but being new to WebAPI i cannot 
get the client access Put Methods.
**Here is my WebAPI Method**

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(string id)
    {          
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Headers.Add("Message","Success");
        return response;
    }    
}
```

**Route Configuration**

```
 //configure the webapi so that it can self host 
 var config = new HttpConfiguration();
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "{Controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

**Client**

```
var baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/";
var client= new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(baseAddress+"Test", "TestParam").Result;
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

When i run the above code.
I get 404 Error for some reason meaning the client cannot contact the webapi method.

**I have three questions.** 
1. How can i make sure the client can correctly call the web api method. 
2. Is it possible to invoke the method directly from url? 
 I tried http://localhost:8000/test/Dummy but no luck.
3. If its possible to invoke the method how can i make sure the message gets displayed on the page saying "Success".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if you didn't specify the action in the configured route. In that case the action is selected by the HTTP method (PUT, POST, DELETE, GET...). The route shpukd look like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "API Default",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

As you've specified the `{action}` part in the route, you must specify the action in the url. In that case, the url should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/Test/Put
```

Please, see [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

If you want to test your Web API methods one of the best tools available is [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), which is a Chrome extenion. This solves your questions 1 & 2.

For Q3: as you're making an asycn call, you have to `await` for the response message, read it, and show the corresponding message. You can [read this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) if you don't know the async/await model.

Comment: Hi JotaBe Thank you for your comment. Yes i did use code based on the routing you suggested.  Even with that  http://localhost:8000/Test/Put doesnt work. Should this be http://localhost:8000/Test/IdName  I read through the documentation for this but the doc doesn't have enough explanation  for put request.

Comment: If you use the route in my answer you can use any action name that starts with Put. The docs explains this: *This convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods*. If it's failing for you it must be some other problem. Please, install and use Postman to create an execute PUT request, and let me know what the answer is. Do other methods like GET or POST work for you?